# Sum showing for blank values

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

Is there any way for the SUM function to show blank if all the cells added are blank? Or any other workaround?

In this picture I try to SUM B11, D11, E11 and H11 with the following function:

```
=SUM(H11,E11,D11,B11)
```

How can I make the sum show blank if there is no data?

[image: sheet screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(SUM(H11,E11,D11,B11)=0,,SUM(H11,E11,D11,B11))
```

or:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(SUM(H11,E11,D11,B11)&"", "^0$", )
```

---

or you can set the color of the font to match color of cell background if 0

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is by taking advantage of the DIV/0 error and the IFERROR() function:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(H11,E11,D11,B11)))
```